# Crystal Report multiple data sources (viewModels) data not display

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, crystal-reports

In Crystal Report how to display data from multiple ViewModels?
Each ViewModel's data gets from different API.

```
var dt1 = query1.Select(a => new ViewModel1
{
   Id = a.Id,
   item = a.item
}).ToList();

rpt.Database.Tables[0].SetDataSource(dt1);
rpt.Database.Tables[1].SetDataSource(dt2);
rpt.Database.Tables[1].SetDataSource(dt3);
```

The result is that display data from Table1, but Table2's data is invisible!

Is that in Crystal Report different data source's data will auto bind the columns?

Comment: You can try putting both `DataTables` dt1 and dt2 in a `DataSet` say ds1 and then set that `DataSet` as data source of the report such as `rpt.SetDataSource(ds1)`

Comment: Actually I used Crystal Reports in ASP.NET MVC, ant the data resources add from different 4 ViewModels. Is that the same as DataSet ?

Comment: After getting your data into dt1 and dt2 from different APIs, aren't these `...Tables[0].SetDataSource(dt1);` and `...Tables[1].SetDataSource(dt2);` statements at one place. If yes, then you should be able to create and use `DataSet` from multiple `DataTables`, if not then you need to show more relevant code.

Comment: I tried another data sources that each ViewModels have the same column, then I can get all data! But when I put the columns form different viewModel, the data counts is not normal. Each data is 8, 5, 5. But I get 2xx. Are they auto bind in the Detials area?